# How to call ajax in jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, apexcharts

I want to create a `dynamic chart` with the help of jQuery. I want to pass `label` and `value` these two array in charts. How can I do that?

Here is the Controller function:

```php
public function chart()
{
    $govtRecievablesStatus = DB::select("select LABEL,round(sum(value)/1000000,1) value from (
        select null as link,LABEL,value from (
        select * from (
        select case when 'ALL'='ALL' then 'ALL' else COMPANY end  as link, LABEL,sum(VALUE) value from(
        select * from APEX_BI_GOVT_RCV_V)
        group by  case when 'ALL'='ALL' then 'ALL' else COMPANY end,LABEL
        )
        where link='ALL')
        union all
        select * from (
        select null as link,'Not Yet due for Filing' label,round(SUM(REBATE_AMOUNT)) value
        from  xx_rebate_refund
        where org_id = 10
        and status = 'NOT_REALIZE')
        where 'AL
        L' in ('USD','ALL'))
        group by LABEL");

    $label=[];
    foreach($govtRecievablesStatus as $gs){
        $label[] = $gs->label;
    }
    // return $label;

    $value= [];
    foreach($govtRecievablesStatus as $gs){
        $value[] = $gs->value;
    }
    // return $value;

    $data = array(
        'label' => $label,
        'value' => $value
    );

    // return $data;
    return view('governmentreceivables::dashboard')->with($data);
}
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // console.log("Hello")
  var e = {
    chart: {
      width: "100%",
      type: "pie"
    },

    ajax: function() {
      var urlPath = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/dashboard';
      var request = $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlPath,
      });
      request.done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
    },
    // obj  = 

    // o.labels ;
    // o.values
    labels: labels,
    value: value,
    // series:[44,55,13,43,22],
    legend: {
      position: "bottom"
    },
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 480,
      options: {
        chart: {
          width: 300
        },
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
          offsetY: 40
        }
      }
    }]
  };
  (t = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#simplePie"), e)).render()
});
```

Please help Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: please share your errors.

Comment: Ajax is not calling @allenski